# Should I say "What are we going to study 'in' / 'by' this presentation?"

Tags: prepositions

When using the presentation in front of audience, what is the correct way to ask what are we going to study by this presentation?

> 1) "What are we going to study **by** this presentation?"
>
> 2) "What are we going to study **in** this presentation?"
>
> 3) "What are we going to study **from** this presentation?"

Comment: More context is needed.  Are you providing something in that presentation to be studied?  Then "in" or "from" can be the required preposition.  If what you are presenting is not the actual study subject, but only the means to study something else, then "in" or "from" are likely not the right ones...

Comment: I mean that I'm going to open PowerPoint in a computer and represent it in front of audience.  Is it clear now? If not, let me know what's needed more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "What are we going to study in this presentation?"

This makes sense if there are specific items that are part of the presentation itself that you have to study.  You would need a copy of the presentation to study them again.

> "What are we going to study from this presentation?"

This makes sense if whoever is giving the presentation is leaving behind things from the presentation to study.  You won't need the original presentation to study these items.

> "What are we going to study by this presentation?"

This makes it sound like you don't know what you are supposed to be studying, but you have to  or want to attend the presentation, and you are wondering what to tell someone else you did.  Alternatively, this can mean that you are asking what to study while you are near a presentation, but not actually attending that presentation.

You most likely want to say *in*.